# Built-in keyboard stopped working on Plasma

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xorg, keyboard, plasma5

I have Arch Linux installed and using Plasma as my DE. Suddenly my laptop's keyboard stopped working on Plasma and on the login screen. It still works on Windows (I have dual boot) and if I switch to the terminal via Ctrl+Alt+F2 (I connected USB Keyboard to do that) it works as well

So, the keyboard does not work in Plasma GUI only

I did some checks and the system sees the keyboard and shows that it's enabled in `xinput`

```
journalctl -b | grep -i translated
Oct 16 12:23:27 archlinux kernel: iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
Oct 16 12:23:27 archlinux kernel: input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
Oct 16 12:23:31 archlinux systemd-logind[435]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
```

```
grep Translated Xorg.0.log
[     8.880] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[     8.880] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     8.880] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     8.880] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     8.880] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     8.883] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     8.883] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[     8.898] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[     8.899] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
[     8.902] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     8.902] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
```

```
    xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Keyboard Consumer Control            id=15 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                            id=17 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control              id=7 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                id=8 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                id=9 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=10 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                             id=11 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                             id=12 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard System Control              id=13 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                             id=14 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam: USB2.0 V          id=16 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                         id=18 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=19 [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard Consumer Control            id=20 [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
xinput list-props "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard':
 Device Enabled (180): 1
 Coordinate Transformation Matrix (182): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
 libinput Send Events Modes Available (300): 1, 0
 libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (301): 0, 0
 libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (302): 0, 0
 Device Node (303): "/dev/input/event4"
 Device Product ID (304): 1, 1
```

What else should I check and what could break it?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else faces this problem, it connected with Asus keyboards and recent kernel update. The workaround is in this thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1922517#p1922517